# Unable to get top and left value

Tags: jquery

I am generating img tag dynamically then providing drag and resize functionality after that I am appending it to the container and then setting its position to the center of the container. This all work fine but after appending when i am retreving top and left position of above added img tag i am getting top 0 and left 0 . When i resize it once then I am getting proper position. Why this is happening .I am totaly cluless. Kindly help.

Below is the code

```
    var img_clip = document.createElement('img');
    $(img_clip).attr("id", "dyndiv" + count);
    $(img_clip).attr("src", current_clip ) ;      
    $(img_clip).attr("width", 30);
    $(img_clip).attr("height",50);                                                                   
      var $ctrl = $(img_clip).resizable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper'}).parent().addClass("resizable").draggable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper', cursor: 'move',delay: 200,distance: 30, opacity: 0.35});
      objid = "dyndiv" + count ;
      $(img_clip).css("z-index" , $(img_clip).css("z-index") + count );
      $('#sel_obj_text').val("Image");
      count++;  
      $("#containment-wrapper").append($ctrl);
           $('#' + objid).parent().position({
                   of: $( "#containment-wrapper" ),
                   my: "center" + " " + "center",
                   at: "center" + " " + "center"
                                                 });
```

later in other piece of code I am trying to get position from below line

```
   $(this).parent().css("left")
  $(this).parent().css("top")
```

Comment: A jsfiddle example would be very helpful in this case! Is `$(this).parent()` an object? If yes, try `$(this).parent().offset().left` (and .top) or if you want the relative position `$(this).parent().position().left`.

Comment: yes $(this).parent()  is a div wrapper created by resize functionality.

Comment: then the `.offset()` and/or `.position()` method should work :)

Comment: both are not working. :(. See my 1 answer  comment

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle.net example. Then we'll figure out where the bug is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am able to solve the problem .

When I change div position from relative to absolute it works.

```
   $(this).parent().css("position","absolute");
```

Regards
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().offset().left
$(this).parent().offset().top
```

Comment: Both are giving 0 even position also . Once i resize the image i start getting correct value.  :(

Comment: I guess you'll need to inspect what your `'this'` points to. If by chance it points to the document object, it will give you `0, 0` always. I suggest putting a break-point before the position code and inspecting what `this` actually contains - to ensure it is indeed pointing to the element you need it to.